# C++ pointer value changes with static_cast

Tags: c, pointers, c++11

I'm seeing weird behavior trying to combine C++ and C code. I'm using a C++ class within C code, using `static_cast` with a `void*` to the class. This is done in the following way.

```
//C++ code
void* newCSPI() {
    return static_cast<void*>(new XSpi);
}
```

This function is declared in the header as follows.

```
//C++ code
extern "C" void* newCSPI(void);
```

I can then call the C++ functions in the C code. An example of the implementation of the other functions is seen below.

```
//C++ code
void selectCSlave(void* spi) {
    static_cast<SPI*>(spi)->selectSlave();
}
```

This function is also declared as `extern "C"` in the header.

This casting function is implemented as follows.

```
//C++ code
void SPI::selectSlave(void) {
    // Select the slave by setting the slave select to low
    XGpio_DiscreteWrite(&slaveSelectDevice, 1, 0x00);
}
```

I'm trying to execute the following block of code. It all succeeds except for the very last line.

```
//C code

void* spi = newCSPI();

/* Select device. */
selectCSlave(spi);

/* Transfer data over SPI*/
transferC(spi, MOSI, MISO, ByteNum);

// It breaks here //

/* Transfer data over SPI*/
transferC(spi, MOSI, MISO, ByteNum);

/* Un-select device. */
deselectCSlave(spi);
```

During the second `transferC(spi)` call, the pointer somehow changes value. Inside the cast function, the pointer still has the same value. Inside the function it is cast to, the value changes. The implementation is exactly the same as the first `transferC(spi)`, which does work. There is no code in between those two calls.

I can't see why the value would suddenly change. What am I missing here?

The code for `deselectCSlave()` and `SPI::deselectSlave(void)`:

```
void deselectCSlave(void* Cspi) {
    static_cast<SPI*>(Cspi)->deselectSlave();
}

void SPI::deselectSlave(void) {
    // Deselects the slave by setting the slave select to high
    XGpio_DiscreteWrite(&slaveSelectDevice, 1, 0xFF);
}
```

The `0x00` and `0xFF` are the values being written.

Comment: Didn't read everything yet, but you can use an opaque struct definition for the typedef, save yourself a whole lot of casting in your implementation.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, having a typedef for `void*` is really confusing - especially when `CSPI` is `void*` but `SPI` is actually some type.

Comment: What makes you think the value changes? Do you tell from the debugger? Perhaps the debugger shows the wrong thing. Does the code still work?

Comment: @KABoissonneault The debugger indeed shows a different value. All properties of the object which is pointed to have changed as well and the code does not work anymore at that point. It gets changed during the `static_cast` call and is thus different and wrong in the underlying function.

Comment: What is the code in `deselectCSlave()`? When you use a debugger to go into that function with a watch on the variable, do you see the point at which it changes?

Comment: @RichardChambers The code in `deselectCSlave()` is added in the question. In the debugger, the value is correct on the `static_cast<SPI*>(Cspi)->deselectSlave();` but after that cast, the value is changed and thus incorrect.

Comment: The block of code you are trying to run, is exactly that? It isn't at all a trimmed down version?

Comment: @StoryTeller In between the final 2 lines, no code has been deleted. The 2nd to last line works, the last line doesn't. Between `selectCSlave()` and `transferC()` is some code that has been deleted in this question. It however all works with the same `spi` and the values of the object `spi` points to stay the same during all the deleted code, up until I indicated where it changes.

Comment: If in `deselectCSlave()` you add a temporary variable, say `SPI *temp = static_cast<SPI *>(Cspi);` then is the value of `Cspi` different from the value of `temp`? What is the difference? This may be one of those rare cases where a C style cast may be necessary. It would be interesting to see the difference by adding two temporary variables, one using a `static_cast` and one using a C style cast.

Comment: Looks like trying OOP with a sledgehammer. Sorry, but why not use standard C code for the whole stuff and encapsulate the SPI handling in a plain C module with a C++ wrapper class? Or write a pure C++ class. But not that hard to understand mixture.

Comment: I just realised I made an error during the debugging process. The value change occurs during the lines I deleted in the question. I've added those lines in the original post. It changes in between the 2 `transferC()` calls. The error however is exactly the same.

Comment: @Olaf The mixture is needed because the C code is the SOES implementation of the Open EtherCat Society. The SPI class is in C++ because we have multiple SPI devices, each with different properties. An OOP approach seemed the best solution.

Comment: You are aware C does support `struct` which can also hold different properties, are you? Just wrap the interface into a class. Anyway, I'm not **your** design architect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cast a pointer to `void*`, the only conversion you're allowed to do to this value is back to the *specific type* from which you converted to a `void*` (well, you can also cast it to a `char*`).

So when you do this:

```
return static_cast<void*>(new XSpi);
```

The only way you can undo that cast is by casting it to `XSpi*`. Therefore, your later cast:

```
static_cast<SPI*>(spi)->selectSlave();
```

That's illegal.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
return static_cast<void*>(static_cast<SPI*>(new XSpi));
```

That will first convert it to the base class (presumably `SPI`), then convert it to `void*`.

Comment: This gives the following error: `invalid static_cast from type XSpi* to type SPI*`

Comment: @Etruscian: The only reason that would be invalid is if `SPI` and `XSpi` were two *completely unrelated* classes. That is, `SPI` is not the base of `XSpi`. I answered your question with the only way it could possibly work. You are saying that your code is fundamentally dysfunctional. If your code isn't broken, then please actually *post* your code, as an [mcve] so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: Should be a dynamic_cast though between SPI * and XSpi* if one inherits from the other

Comment: @sokkyoku: Not if SPI is a base class. It's always legal to `static_cast` a derived class to a base class. It's the reverse that requires a `dynamic_cast` (unless you have specific knowledge of that instance's type).

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks to your comment, I fixed the issue. The return statement for the `newCSPI(void)` should have been: 
`return static_cast<void*>(new SPI);` XSpi is a struct defined in C, which made it illegal to cast a class pointer from it. The `SPI` class uses this struct, which caused the confusion on my side.